# Is there a keyboard shortcut for renaming files in GTK file chooser dialog?

Tags: gtk

So GTK finally [implemented](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325150) file renaming and deleting of files (not moving) in its File chooser dialogue. However, one must right click to achieve that, <kbd>F2</kbd> as the default shortcut for renaming file does not work and neither does <kbd>Delete</kbd> for removing them. Are there other shortcuts? Can they be changed?

Comment: What version do you see with `apt policy libgtk-3-0`? And could you include a link for "GTK finally impemented file renaming and deleting of files (not moving) in its File chooser dialogue"?

Comment: Link added, the version is 3.22.30-1ubuntu1, this is on Ubuntu 18.04.